# Is Simba ODBC faster that google bigquery Api for PHP?

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

Hello Im new with GCP and I want to know if Simba ODBC is more faster to get data that google API for PHP?

Recenlty I have problems in time to execution for get data with PHP, I worked with bigquery api for nodejs and I noticed that in this is more faster, but with the bigquery API for PHP this not happend.

So i want to know if using Simba it is better.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, there really is only one true answer to such "Is A faster then B?" kind of questions, and that one is:

**Measure it.**

That is, measure the time required by both methods (preferrably multiple times to eliminate noise), then compare the results and draw your conclusions.

In some case one might be able to give a general tendency for a generic case, but that may or may not be in line with your use case. So again: Measuring it is the only correct answer.